# Is it possible to give an ASP.NET MVC User Control a different Model than the Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, user-controls

I have an order page that is being rendered from a Model object (Order) with a few properties.  One of the properties of the Order object is

```
public List<OrderItem> Items { get; set; };
```

and the other is

```
public List<OrderComment> Comments { get; set; };
```

My main page is declared like this:

```
public class OrderView : ViewPage<Order>
```

I want to have a User Control for each OrderItem (named OrderItemControl), and another User Control for each OrderComment (named OrderCommentControl).  If I could use a repeater for each collection then that would be great, but I am running into a problem.  I want my user control declarations to looks like this:

```
public class OrderItemControl : ViewUserControl<OrderItem>
public class OrderCommentControl : ViewUserControl<OrderComment>
```

I get an error when I try to do this saying:

{"The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Order' but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'OrderItem'."}

I am guessing repeater might not be the right way to go, but I really want each User Control to have a model of type OrderItem or OrderComment, and not just Order.

Comment: I didn't have any problems with this the last time I tried; it sounds like you haven't passed the right object to the user control.

Comment: How do you get the associated OrderComment given an OrderItem?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Using `RenderPartial` you can use the signature that supplies the model and simply use  whatever model object is available to you in the current View.

```
<% foreach (OrderItem orderItem in ViewData.Model.OrderItems)
   {
 %>
       <%= Html.RenderPartial( "OrderItem", orderItem, ViewData ) %>
<% } %>
```

You can poke around in the actual source at http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet.  Click on the Source tab and navigate down to the MVC source tree.

Comment: You shouldn't need to specify the path to your user control unless they're in a non standard location.

Comment: @Todd Smith -- I wasn't sure and didn't have a sample in front of me.  Thanks.  Now, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your call to render the user control passes the right data the Render function.

(My memories of the current object model for ViewData are fuzzy, but that should be close).

See 
[this old post from Rob Conery](http://blog.wekeroad.com/2008/01/07/aspnet-mvc-using-usercontrols-usefully/)